# unique_ptr assignment and copy constructor clarification

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, glfw

I would like to ensure the code I have (which does work) is correct to the specifications to c++. As in I want to make sure that all though it does run fine that the code meets c++ standards and specifications. Not entirely sure if this should rather be in a code review forum. If so please direct me there and I will move this post over to the forum.

Engine.h

```
class Engine final {
public:
    void run();
    void startup();
    Logger& getLogger() const;

    Engine() = default;
    ~Engine() = default;
    Engine(Engine&& engine) = delete;
    Engine(const Engine& engine) = delete;
    Engine& operator=(Engine&& engine) = delete;
    Engine& operator=(const Engine& engine) = delete;

    void registerWindow(Window&& window);
    void registerWindow(Window& window);
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Logger> m_logger;
    std::unique_ptr<Window> m_main_window;
};
```

Engine.cpp

```
void Engine::registerWindow(Window &&window) {
    m_main_window = std::move(std::unique_ptr<Window>(&window)); // not confident that this is technically correct.
}

void Engine::registerWindow(Window &window) {
    m_main_window = std::move(std::unique_ptr<Window>(&window)); // not confident that this is technically correct.
}
```

Window.h

```
class Window {
public:
    Window(std::string title, int32_t width, int32_t height);
    ~Window() = default;
    Window(const Window& window) = delete;
    Window(Window&& window) noexcept ;
    Window& operator=(const Window& window) = delete;
    Window& operator=(Window&& window) noexcept ;
    void make_current() const;
    GLFWwindow* window() const;
private:
    std::unique_ptr<GLFWwindow, GLFWdeleter> m_window;
};
```

Window.cpp

```
Window::Window(Window &&window) noexcept
    : m_window(std::move(window.m_window))
{
}

Window &Window::operator=(Window &&window) noexcept {
    if (this == &window)
        return *this;
    m_window = std::move(m_window);
    return *this;
}
```

main.cpp

```
Window window("Hello World!", 640, 480);
window.make_current();
g_engine.registerWindow(window);
```

Comment: You should take `std::unique_ptr<Window>` for `Engine::registerWindow`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I was thinking that would be better. Could you elaborate further as to the reason? I am assuming it has to do with it being a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: The move in `std::move(std::unique_ptr<T>(p))` is unneeded.

Comment: You want to transfer ownership, and you doing that by "pointer" (reference in your case, which is even less clear). `Window&&` would be acceptable if you store Window by value.

Comment: yes this is very true. So I should be passing in a `unique_ptr` and using `std::move()` to pass ownership to the pointer in the engine class?

Comment: Typo: `m_window = std::move(m_window);` should be `m_window = std::move(window.m_window);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RegisterWindow

```
std::unique_ptr<Window> m_main_window; // for reference.

void Engine::registerWindow(Window &&window) 
{
    m_main_window = std::move(std::unique_ptr<Window>(&window)); // NOT CORRECT!
                                                                 // crash waiting to happen!
}
```

`std::unique_ptr<>` is a thin wrapper for pointers allocated with new.  In other words `delete m_main_window.get()` **will** be called from Engine's destructor.  In addition, it is terrible practice to keep a pointer to a value passed by reference, as there is no guarantee that the `window` object will live as long as Engine::m_main-window.

As pointed out by @Jarod42, you should consider receiving a std::unique_ptr as a parameter to `RegisterWindow()`

```
void Engine::registerWindow(std::unique_ptr<Window> wnd) 
{
    m_main_window = std::move(wnd);
}

// call as
std::unique_ptr<Window> w(new Window);
engine.registerWindow(std::move(w));
```

This ensures that the caller understands that `wnd` *must* be allocated with new.  And that Engine will take ownership of the pointer.

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented the changes. I have one question though should you not be setting the passed `unique_ptr` to `nullptr` as it is no longer the owner?

Comment: `wnd`was reset when its contents was moved to `m_main_window`.  unique_ptr goes to great lengths to ensure there is only one copy of the pointer.

Comment: https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/ : Pass `unique_ptr` by value by default.

Comment: Does indeed make sense.

Comment: @Jarod42 I dont think I agree with that article that you should pass by value because for it to work you need to `std::move()` twice purely for readability. The person using my software should be well aware of how it works and should know that it is moving ownership

Comment: The whole point is that the user should call move.  A unique_ptr move is 4 instructions on most machines.  The C++ paradigm is to make it impossible to misuse your interface...

Comment: BTW, there are discussions for `registerWindow(std::unique_ptr<Window>)` vs `registerWindow(std::unique_ptr<Window>&&)` as http://scottmeyers.blogspot.fr/2014/07/should-move-only-types-ever-be-passed.html